# Regex to redirect 301 a folder and all posts from that folder in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Just moved my website from `www.example.com/blog` to `www.example.com`.

I need to add a 301 redirect to my `.htaccess` to redirect everything that is called with the `www.example.com/blog/...` url, like a `www.example.com/blog/category` to `www.example.com/category` or `www.example.com/blog/post-title` to `www.example.com/post-title`.

I've redirected the folder but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help me?

This is the code with the 301 of the folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your site root .htaccess have this rule at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks! /blog folder doesn't exist anymore. I've migrated the website and am doing this just to fix the broken links on the /.

Comment: Does that redirecting only when `example.com/blog` is called?

Comment: It's actually returning `http://post-title` when I visit `http://example.com/blog/post-title`

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Updated the question with the rules I'm using in `htaccess`

Comment: Try first rule as: `RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

Comment: Great! It worked! I'm going to edit your answer and accept it as correct! Thanks @anubhava !

Comment: It's not working. =( I'm having a server internal error now.

Comment: Internal server error is caused by some bad syntax or typo. Check Apache error.log for exact cause of 500